# undefined reference to by using auto from cpp 17

Tags: c++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I try compile this code

```
#include <utility>                                                               
#include <stdexcept>                                                             
#include <tuple>                                                                 
#include <typeinfo>                                                              
#include <iostream>                                                              

int main(int argc, char** argv) {                                                
std::pair<int, int> divide_remainder(int dividend, int divisor);               
const auto result (divide_remainder(16, 3));                                   

// auto [fraction, remainder] = divide_remainder(16, 3);                       
// const auto result (divide_remainder(16, 3));                                
//std::cout << "16 / 3 is " << result.first << " with a remainder of "         
    //<< result.second << '\n';                                                 
 return 0;                                                                      
}
```

with that command

```
g++  -std=c++1z featuresMain.cpp
```

and get this error

> ```
> featuresMain.cpp:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `divide_remainder(int, int)'
> ```

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please format your code.  You have declared `divide_remainder` but have not implemented it.

Comment: C != C++. Please tag only with the language you're actually using.

Comment: Show us the implementation of `divide_remainder`.

Comment: oh shit yeah it would be an good idea to implement it first

Comment: I start haven't seen that I have the code from a book Thank you all for your answers